# Rails 4, loading api response in memory for drop down select?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, api

Basically I want to pull a list of team objects from an API - the team_id and the team_name is what I'm interested in - as it will allow me to make pertitent API calls later on and to populate a drop down list with options. I want to have the list of 'team names' available in a drop down list, inside of a form used to create a carpool object in my application.

So Far I have this:

**carpool_controller.rb** (carpools#ts_add_teams_to_memory) controller action being called:

```
  def ts_add_teams_to_memory
      ts_teams = current_user.ts_add_teams_to_memory
  end
```

Where, ts_teams is an array of hashes containing keys [:name] and [:id]. 
ts_add_teams_to_memory

- grabs teams from the api
- pulls out attributes 'name' and 'id'
- creates a hash for each object
- passes that hash into an array.
- ts_teams represents that array of hashes.

**carpools/new.html.erb**

Here is the form I want to pass the array of hashes into via ajax.

```
  <%= form_for @carpool do |f| %>
    <h3>Select Team</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.collection_select :team_id, #INSERT ARRAY OF HASHES VIA AJAX?, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
    </div>
      <%= f.submit 'Create Carpool', :class => 'button left' %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the link I am using to send the ajax request to the correct path:

```
    <%= link_to "Get Teams", ts_add_teams_to_memory_path(current_user.id),
            remote: true,
            method: :get,
            class: "btn btn-success left",
            data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#ts_loading"} %>
```

How do I push the array of hashes into the collection_select tag in the carpool create form? Or, is there a better way to do this? I need to see the list of team options returned from the API on the page, ideally without reloading the page...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should render the `collection_select` in the javascript view.  the action that your `link_to` is calling should `respond_to do |format| format.js end` and then your view will end with `js.erb` and you can use jquery to insert the `collection_select` with the data you want in there.  You should not have to write any javascript explicitly calling the `ajax(...)` method.  That's the whole point of rails unobtrusive javascript.  It is explained quite well here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write some javascript code to do that.

To do it yourself in coffeescript, it will be something like that:

```
$('#ajax-id').on 'ajax:success', (data) ->
  data.teams.forEach (team) ->
    $('#select-id').append("<option value=#{team.id}>#{name}</option>")
```

Change the `#xxx-ids` to the ajax form and select element IDs respectively.

I recommend trying one of the following javascript libraries to make your life a whole lot easier:

- [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)
- [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

They both have remote data support using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out

Comment: I added an example of how to do it yourself in coffeescript, but it's probably not worth the hassle if you have lots of this sort of remote dropdowns, especially if they get more complex. =)

Comment: Was thinking about using react - could be a bit over kill at this point. That looks like an elegant solution. And this code will allow me to keep using the rails tag collection_select tag no sweat?

Comment: In this case - my "#ajax-id" would be the id of my link_to tag i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Controller (make sure you call `ts_add_teams_to_memory` in your action):

```
def ts_add_teams_to_memory
  @ts_teams = current_user.ts_add_teams_to_memory
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.collection_select :team_id, @ts_teams, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: This method requires a page fresh. Not what I'm after - needs to be done with ajax. I want to avoid saving the data from the api - I understand that after the page refresh, that data will no longer be available.